# Paramiko: "Must be connected to a terminal."

Tags: python, ssh, paramiko

I am trying to use Paramiko to access the input and output of a program running inside of a screen session. Let's assume there is a screen `screenName` with a single window running the program I wish to access the I/O of. When I try something like `client.exec_command('screen -r screenName')` for example, I get the message "Must be connected to a terminal" in the stdout.

Searching around, I learned that for some programs, one needs to request a "pseudo-terminal" by adding the `get_pty=True` parameter to `exec_command`. When I try this, my code just hangs, and my terminal becomes unresponsive.

What else can I try to make this work?

To provide a little more context to my problem, I am creating a web app that allows users to perform basic operations that I have previously done only in a PuTTy terminal. A feature I wish to have is a kind of web terminal designed to interact with the input and output of this particular program. Effectively all I want to do is continuously pipe output from the program to my backend, and pipe input to the program.

Comment: You don't need (or want) `screen` for that.  You just want to run the app.  You can't connect to a `screen` session from a non-interactive source.

Comment: `screen` seems like the easiest way to keep track of the program between terminal sessions without keeping track of a process id or something. This program will be running independently of whether anyone needs to access it at a particular moment. It's just a server which ideally always runs in the background.

Comment: Yes, it is, but you cannot attach to a `screen` session from a web server.  It requires a terminal.  You need to run the app directly with something line `subprocess.Popen` and capture the output.  That's not very hard, but `screen` will not be a player.

Comment: I don't think I'm understanding. `subprocess.Popen` would be used to open a process running on the same computer. My web server isn't running on the same PC as the PC I am trying to ssh into order to access this app a priori.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I glossed over your details here.  You should be able to ssh into your other computer using paramiko, but you'll have to run commands without `screen`.